# Keep significant zeros using str(float) in python

Tags: python, string, significant-digits

Considering the code below. The output of this is 2.76 but for the application I am using it for, the zero after 2.76 is significant thus I am searching for a way to output 2.760.

```
f = 2.7598
r = round(f,3)
s = str(r)
print(s)
```

Comment: [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) should help.

Comment: If your application is "decimal-centric" and the idea of significant digits/precision is important to you, consider using the decimal library https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the conversion to `string` and use simply use `format()`:

```
f = 2.7598
r = round(f,3)
print(format(r, '.3f'))
```

**Result:**

```
2.760
```

Or if you need a `string` for whatever reason:

```
f = 2.7598
r = round(f,3)
s = format(r, '.3f')
print(s)
```

Comment: The formatting will round too, so if the value doesn't need to be rounded for mathematical purposes, just for display, you can `format` without the `round` call.